# How to disable redirection

Tags: magento-1.7, redirect, development

Here is my problem: I am trying to set up a development copy of a running Magento website. I created a subdomain, copied all the files to the /dev directory, made a copy of the database, set up the new credentials in `/dev/etc/local.xml`, change the secure and unsecure URL in `core_config_data`, but when I try to access the dev page I am always redirected to the live page.

I checked the `.htaccess` files, I actually cleared it at one point, I disabled Auto-redirect to Base URL (both on the live and the dev version), but the page is still getting redirected.

What and where should I look to get this issue resolved.

Here is the live version of the site: www.example.com
Dev version should be here: dev.example.com or www.example.com/dev

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sounds like a caching issue. Assuming you are using `file` cache, delete everything from `dev/var/cache`. If that doesn't work it could be the classic "the cache isn't where you think it is" problem. If 'dev/var/cache' isn't writable then the cache may get created in `/tmp/magento/`.

Comment: Yes, this solved the issue, thank you! At least lumeabasmelor.ro/dev is working, but dev.lumeabasmelor.ro not. Also I can't login to the admin panel, any idea what to set and where? Sorry for all the questions, but I have been blocked here since december 20th :)

Comment: To make the dev subdomain work you'll probably have to either a.) create a new VirtualHost that points directly to the dev folder, or b.) edit the .htaccess on the LIVE site to redirect to `/dev/index.php` if the domain is `dev.lumeabasmelor.ro`. Personally I'd recommend a.) if at all possible.

Comment: Option a.) is not possible, I tried option b.), dev.lumeabasmelor.ro works, but when I try to log in to dev.lumeabasmelor.ro/admin it always redirects me to www.lumeabasmelor.ro/admin and asking me to log in again.

Comment: When you go to dev.lumeabasmelor.ro/admin, you're probably actually looking at the live site.

Comment: Yeah but the same thing happens when I go to lumeabasmelor.ro/dev/index.php/admin

Comment: This actually worked for me! :D

Answer (score 2):

In my case cache is stored in my root tmp folder.I have delete all zend_cache* then it works.

Comment: This was it for me. `/tmp/magento/var/cache` was added automatically. I removed the cached files and immediately tried my dev URL again and it no longer redirected to the production URL. Thank you.